Python: Post and Get as a Queue
We have an API in a cloud that accepts audio recordings and returns features. I would now like to send a number n of audio recordings to the API and whenever I receive features of a recording back, a new request for features of a recording should be pushed from behind. This should be possible with a queue, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet.
With my current method, only one chunk is processed at a time and the next chunk is sent after it (see below). But how can I ensure that there is always a refill from the back while the front is being processed?
URL = 'https://url_post/post'

URL_features =\
'https://url_get/features'

file_paths = file_paths_names_background['file_paths']

chunk_size = 30

nr_of_chunks = math.ceil(len(file_paths) / chunk_size)

file_paths_chunks = lst_in_chunks(file_paths, chunk_size)

res = []

error_lst = []

rest_time = 1

t0 = time.time()

count = 0

verbose = -1


for file_paths_chunk in tqdm(file_paths_chunks,
                         file=sys.stdout
                         ):

    print(f'\nProcess chunk {count} of {nr_of_chunks}.')

    client_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    
    res_post = await post_audio_files(URL,
                                      file_paths_chunk,
                                      client_session,
                                      tqdm_switch=False)
    
    error_lst += check_resp_lst_for_erros(res_post)

    print(f'\n\tPost: {len(error_lst)} errors.')

    client_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    resp_features = await get_features_via_tokens(url = URL_features,
                                            resp_dict_in =\
                            [res_dict for res_dict in res_post if res_dict['status_code'] == 200],
                                            client_session = client_session)    
    
    res = res + concat_post_feat_resp(resp_posts = res_post,
                                      resp_feats = resp_features)    
    
    if verbose > -1:
        
        print(f'\n\tRest for {rest_time} seconds.')
        
    time.sleep(rest_time)
    
    print('# ------------------------------------ #')

    count += 1

t1 = time.time()

print('----------------------------------')
print(f'\nUploaded all {len(file_paths)} files.')
print(f"\n--> Elapsed time: {t1 - t0} s.")
print('----------------------------------')

async def post_audio_files(url: str = None,
                           file_paths: list = None,
                           client_session: 'aiohttp.ClientSession()' = None,
                           tqdm_switch: bool = False,
                           verbose: int = -1):

    t0 = time.time()

    if verbose > -1:

        print('\n# --------------------------------------- #')
        print(f"\nThe posting of {len(file_paths)} audio files started at : {datetime.now()}.")

    if tqdm_switch:

        async with client_session as session:
            res = await tqdm_asyncio.gather(*[post_audio_file(url = url,
                                                      file_path = file_path,
                                                      session = session)\
                                         for file_path in file_paths])

        

    else:

        async with client_session as session:
            res = await asyncio.gather(*[post_audio_file(url = url,
                                                      file_path = file_path,
                                                      session = session)\
                                         for file_path in file_paths])

    if verbose > -1:
        
        print(f'\n\tAll {len(res)} files have been uploaded.')
    
    t1 = time.time()

    if verbose > -1:
        
        print(f"\nUploading the files and gathering the tokens ended at {datetime.now()}.")
        print(f"\n\t--> Elapsed time: {t1 - t0} s.")
    
        print('\n# --------------------------------------- #')

    return res

async def get_features_stat200(url: str = None,
                               token_file_name_lst: list = None,
                               client_session: 'aiohttp.ClientSession()' = None,
                               rest_count: int = 1,
                               verbose: int = -1):
    
    t0 = time.time()

    if verbose > -1:

        print(f"\nThe gathering of the features of {len(token_file_name_lst)} files "\
              f"started at: {datetime.now()}.")
    
    
    async with client_session as session:

        animation = "|/-\\"
        idx = 0
        
        results_bool_lst = [False]

        results = []
        
        while not all(results_bool_lst):
            print(f'\n---- {inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name}')
            print(f'---- Iteration {idx+1} ---- \nGather and check for results: ', animation[idx % len(animation)], end="\r")
            idx += 1
            
            results_current = await tqdm_asyncio.gather(*[get_feature(url = url,
                                                     file_name = token_file_name[1],
                                                     token = token_file_name[0],
                                                     session = session)\
                                     for token_file_name in token_file_name_lst])

            results_bool_lst = [False if resp_dict['status_code'] != 200 else True for resp_dict in results_current]

            status_codes = [resp_dict['status_code'] for resp_dict in results_current if resp_dict['status_code'] != 200]

            token_file_name_lst = [(resp_dict['token'], resp_dict['file_name'])\
                                    for resp_dict in results_current if resp_dict['status_code'] != 200]

            # results += [resp_dict for resp_dict in results_current if resp_dict['status_code'] == 200]

            results += results_current

            print(f"\n\tCurrent successful responses: {len(\
                [resp_dict for resp_dict in results_current if resp_dict['status_code'] == 200]\
            )}")
            print(f"\n\tCurrent unsuccessful responses: {len(token_file_name_lst)}")
            print(f'\t\tStatus codes: {set(status_codes)}')
            
            break_lst = [True if resp_dict['status_code'] == 500 else False for resp_dict in results_current]

            # If the only tokens that are still in the loop
            # only have the code 500, then break
            if all(break_lst):

                print('Current results: ', len(results_current))

                break

            if not all(results_bool_lst):            
                show_countdown(rest_count)
            
    print(f'\n\tReceived features from {len(\
        [resp_dict for resp_dict in results_current if resp_dict['status_code'] == 200]\
    )} tokens.')

    t1 = time.time()
        
    print(f"\nGathering the features ended at {datetime.now()}.")
    print(f"\n\t--> Elapsed time: {t1 - t0} s.")

    return results

